# rsa routines:RSA_check_key_ex:d e not congruent to 1, error while loading rsa xml file in .netcore on linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rsa, .net-6.0, linux-containers

I have a RSA XML file which I am trying to load using below code in .NET 6.0. This works fine on Windows container but fails on Linux container with error:

> rsa routines:RSA_check_key_ex:d e not congruent to 1

```
var rsaCryptoServiceProvider = RSA.Create();
rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(data);
```

As per https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO29559.html, this message comes when key is compromised. But why it's working on windows and not on linux container.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: The same certificate need to be used on Windows and linux.  TLS the server sends a certificate block with names of possible certificates.  Than client looks up the name of certificates.  It finding the xml file but having issues opening the file on linux.  Check the permissions of the xml file (certificate).  If you have an old version of linux it may not be able to use the encryption mode in certificate and you need to update the linux encryption.   You may have an old version of Open SSL.

Comment: This will be hard to figure out without an example file that generates the exception.

Comment: Thank You, I was able to resolve this by uploading the file in windows container and exporting it into another file then using the exported file in linux. The newly exported file is working on both windows and linux.